# Did SQ-242, fly from Sydney to Singapore on 8th April 2020?

Tags: australia, covid-19, singapore-airlines

Was Flight No SQ-242 Singapore Airlines from Sydney to Singapore on 8th April 2020, cancelled due to the Corona virus and border controls in Australia?

Answer (score 4):

**No, it did not fly**.

The last [flight data](https://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/SIA242) for a SQ 242 flight was on Saturday, 28 March, 2020:

[image]